# backbone.js + tastypie: how to allow anyone to access API

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

For a variety of reasons, I would like anyone to be able to save backbone models in my app, but they keep encountering a 401 authorization error when they try to save a model to the server. How can I let anyone make successful POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

When using Tastypie along with Django, you can set the Authentication attribute, look [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html) for further reference.